# How do I find the "string number" of a given string, in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, search, find

I have the following array of strings:

```
array = ["fox jumps", "snail slides", "airplane flies"];
```

I'm trying to find the string in the array containing "airplane", and return the string number in the array.

I have the following code so far:

```
var array = ["fox jumps", "snail slides", "airplane flies"];
var el = array.find(a =>a.includes("airplane"));
console.log(el)
```

...which finds the string "airplane flies"

From this point, how do I return the string number? in this example, it should be "3"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) almost does what you want, but note that arrays in JS are zero-based, and since you want a one-based result (you want to return `3` for the third element in the array, not `2`), you need to add one:

```js
var el = array.findIndex(a =>a.includes("airplane")) + 1;
```